# greatest common divisor for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $f(x), g(x)\in k [x]$. The greatest common divisor is defined to the monic common divisor having largest degree.  In this definition, can the condition $k$ being a field be weakened to $k$ being a commutative ring? That is, is it well-defined due to the uniqueness?

Comment: @WillJagy $\Bbb Z$ is actually not an appropriate example here, since it is a UFD, and hence $\Bbb Z[x]$ is again a UFD and $\gcd$ is well-defined on $\Bbb Z[x]$. There are plenty of examples though.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "well-defined". Are you asking merely if it is a well-defined operation or if, additionally, it  yields a correct definition of the gcd? And, btw, what  definition of "gcd" are you using?

Answer (score -1):

For example, the gcd of $2x+1$ and $(2x+1)x$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ is $x+\frac{1}{2}$, which is not in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

So we cannot just replace $k$ with any commutative ring. This is really because of the monic condition on the gcd; we can divide by the leading entry when working in $k$, but this is not always possible in a general commutative ring.

Comment: Nevertheless, $\gcd$ of two polynomials is well-defined in $\Bbb Z[x]$. There are more intrinsic examples...

Comment: @WhatsUp But the OP is asking for the gcd to be under the given definition, which includes the monic condition. In particular, the uniqueness goes out the window in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: If we adapt that definition, then it would say: $\gcd(f, g)$ is defined as the monic polynomial $h\in \Bbb Z[x]$ with highest degree such that $h$ divides both $f$ and $g$. Then the $\gcd$ of $2x + 1$ and $(2x+1)x$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is simply $1$, which is well-defined: because no monic polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$ of degree $> 0$ divides both polynomials.

Comment: @WhatsUp I suppose, but that would seem like a poor definition to use.

Comment: But that's what the question is asking... and the current answer obviously does not answer the question correctly. Perhaps change it to an example with $k$ non-integral?